# How to show a topological space is compact and if it's from a metric or not?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

We have $X$ is an infinite set and $\tau=\{U\subset X:X \backslash U$ is finite or is all of $X \}$. Till now, I have proved that $\tau$ is a topology and is not Hausdorf, but how can I show if it's compact? I really want to know how we should apply the definition. And in general how can we see if a topology comes from a metric or not? Hope you can help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $X$. Pick any $U_0\in\mathscr{U}$, and let $F=X\setminus U_0$; by definition $F$ is finite. How many open sets from $\mathscr{U}$ do you need to be sure of covering each point of $F$?

Comment: But why do we consider covering each point of $F$ but not $X$? But let me try. Since $F$ is finite, we only need finitely many open sets from $u$ , the open cover of X(sorry, don't know how to type the u). but I don't know how is it related to the proof?

Comment: @Cancan: The set $U_0$ already covers all of $X$ except $F$. As you say, it takes only finitely many more members of $\mathscr{U}$ to cover $F$. If it takes $n$ members of $\mathscr{U}$ to cover $F$, then it takes $n+1$ to cover all of $X$: just throw in the set $U_0$. To be precise about it, for each $x\in F$ there is a $U_x\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $x\in U_x$. Let $\mathscr{U}_0=\{U_0\}\cup\{U_x:x\in F\}$; then $\mathscr{U}_0$ is a finite subfamily of $\mathscr{U}$ that covers $X$.

Comment: @Cancan: You can find out how any formula was produced by right-clicking on it and selecting `Show Math As` and `TeX Commands`. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a primer on writing math on this site, with some useful links as well.

Comment: Oh, what a great explanation! Thank you very much, Brian!

Comment: @Cancan: You’re most welcome.

Comment: Sorry to ask the other question. Generally, do you know how we can see if a topology comes from a metric? What I know is that a metric can be defined on a topology but I don't know how a topology comes from a metric.

Comment: @Cancan: There are theorems that characterize the topologies that come from metrics, but in practice it can be quite difficult to tell that one does. It’s often quite easy to tell that one **doesn’t**, however. For instance, this one doesn’t, because every metric topology is Hausdorff. Similarly, every metric topology is first countable, so a topology that isn’t first countable can’t come from a metric.

Comment: Cool, I get your point. Since I just started learning those concepts in analysis, I don't really know what "first countable" means, could you please briefly explain that? Thanks :)

Comment: @Cancan: $X$ is [first countable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable_space) if each point of $X$ has a countable neighborhood base. That is, for each $x\in X$ there is a countable family $\mathscr{B}(x)$ of open nbhds of $x$ such that if $U$ is **any** open nbhd of $x$, there is some $B\in\mathscr{B}(x)$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$. If the set $X$ in your question is uncountable, $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is not first countable: no point of $X$ has a countable nbhd base.

Comment: I see. Really like your explanation! :D

Comment: do you think this topology is compact? $\tau=\{U\subset X: X\backslash U$ is countable or is all of $X\}$. From the technique you gave me, I think it's not. Because $F=X\backslash U_0$ is countable, and in order to cover $F$, finite sets cannot work if $F$ infinitely countable. I am not sure, how do you think about it?

Comment: @Cancan: You’re right: it’s not, though the fact that the technique that we used before doesn’t work here isn’t enough to prove that the space isn’t compact. To do that, let $C=\{x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ be a countably infinite subset of $X$. Let $U=X\setminus C$, and for each $n$ let $U_n=U\cup\{x_n\}$. Now show that $\{U_0,U_1,U_2,\dots\}$ is an open cover of $X$ that has no proper subcover at all, let alone a finite subcover.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott by no proper subcover you mean that the only subcover is the set $U_n$ itself?

Comment: @Albanian_EAGLE: The only subcollection of $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ that covers $X$ is $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ itself.